# How do I convert txt file to xml?

Tags: php, xml

What I am trying to do is convert my .txt file to xml. I get everything together inside of one tag rather that it being each one in their own tags.

```
$fp = fopen('notes.txt', 'r');
$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openURI('notes.xml');
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startElement('Notes');
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
   $xml->startElement('note');
   $xml->writeElement('dateTime', $line[0]);
   $xml->writeElement('Operation', $line[1]);
   $xml->writeElement('table', $line[2]);
   $xml->writeElement('user', $line[3]);
   $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
```

This is what I get:

```
<Notes>
 <note>
  <dateTime>2014-03-26 02:43:32     Insert     Products     Admin</dateTime>
  <Operation/>
  <table/>
  <user/>
 </note>
 <note>
  <dateTime>2014-03-26 02:53:04     Insert     Products     Admin</dateTime>
  <Operation/>
  <table/>
  <user/>
 </note>
 <note>
  <dateTime>2014-03-26 02:58:13     Insert     Products     Admin</dateTime>
  <Operation/>
  <table/>
  <user/>
 </note>
 <note>
</Notes>
```

Time is in it's correct tag, but "insert" is supposed to be in operation, "products" in table and "admin" in user. How can I fix this so that it places it in correctly?

This is my .txt file:

```
2014-03-26 02:43:32     Insert     Products     Admin
2014-03-26 02:53:04     Insert     Products     Admin
2014-03-26 02:58:13     Insert     Products     Admin
```

Comment: well you will need to parse ( not only reading/dumping) your .txt input line by line. On the first look `split()` would work fine

Comment: Your txt file is not comma separated. You should configure a delimiter for fgetcsv(). Is it a tab you use as delimiter ("\t")?

Comment: Split is deprecated. Use explode instead

Comment: @scrowler that must be right ;-) havent been using php since ages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either change the txt file to use a "," as delimiter or configure one for [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

```
$fp = fopen('notes.txt', 'r');
$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openURI('notes.xml');
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startElement('Notes');
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) {
   $xml->startElement('note');
   $xml->writeElement('dateTime', $line[0]);
   $xml->writeElement('Operation', $line[1]);
   $xml->writeElement('table', $line[2]);
   $xml->writeElement('user', $line[3]);
   $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
```

Answer (score 1):

try `explode()`

not sure about file spaces but you need to print array `$lines` after explode what you have result and set according to your result

```
while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
 $lines = explode(' ', $line);
   $xml->startElement('note');
   $xml->writeElement('dateTime', $lines[0]. ' '. $lines[1]);
   $xml->writeElement('Operation', $lines[2]);
   $xml->writeElement('table', $lines[3]);
   $xml->writeElement('user, $lines[4]);
   $xml->endElement();
}
```

Comment: Tab spacing would be better as using a space delimiter restricts the data fields to only being one word